# Money Denominations in C

Tags: c, do-while

can anybody help me with my code

```
int main(void){

int money, x[6],i[6];

x[0] = 1000; x[1] = 500; x[2] = 200; x[3] = 100; x[4] = 50; x[5] = 20;

printf("Enter your Money: ");
scanf("%d", &money);

printf("\nBreakdown:\n");

for(int y=0;money != 0; y++){

    i[y] = ( money - (money % x[y]) )/x[y];
    money = (money % x[y]);

    printf("%10d  x  %d  =  %5d \n", x[y], i[y], (x[y] * i[y]));

}
printf("---------------------------\n");
printf("Total:");
printf("                  %d", money);
```

getch();

}

how to check if there is a remainder & it will say Invalid Input

Comment: If you want help then you need to describe what problem you are having with your code. Specifically, what is the input, the expected behaviour/output and the actual behaviour/output? And please don't post text as images as it prevents people from copying that text for use in answers/comments.

Comment: This is not a question. Please read the [help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help). However, if you're wondering why your program is exiting with a segmentation error, think about what will happen to the value of `y` if `money` is not a multiple of 20 or 50. (Perhaps changing `money != 0` to `y < 6` would be a good idea.)

Comment: in for loop you can check `money != 0 && y<6)` so that loop will not run more than 6 time. Otherwise you can add more values to array like `x[6]=5`, `x[7]=2`, `x[8]=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add more values to array like x[6]=5, x[7]=2, x[8]=1, which i think will be best Idea.
so that you can calculate multiple of 5,2 and 1 also.
Otherwise

you can do something like this.

```
int nTemp = money; //Take a temp variable to store total money 
for(int y=0;money != 0 && y<6; y++){ // check both money!=0 and y should be less than 6

    i[y] = ( money - (money % x[y]) )/x[y];
    money = (money % x[y]);

    printf("%10d  x  %d  =  %5d \n", x[y], i[y], (x[y] * i[y]));
}
if(money>0) // if remainder is there you can print
   printf("Remaining change = %d\n", money);

printf("---------------------------\n");
printf("Total:");
printf("                  %d", nTemp); // print nTemp here, i.e total money
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version which works with all inputs, not just those divisible by 20.

```
int main(void){

    int money, money2, x[7],i[7], y;

    x[0] = 1000; x[1] = 500; x[2] = 200; x[3] = 100; x[4] = 50; x[5] = 20, x[6] = 1;

    printf("Enter your Money: ");
    scanf("%d", &money);
    money2 = money;

    printf("\nBreakdown:\n");

    for(y=0;money >0; y++){

        i[y] = ( money - (money % x[y]) )/x[y];
        money = (money % x[y]);

        printf("%10d  x  %d  =  %5d \n", x[y], i[y], (x[y] * i[y]));

    }
    printf("---------------------------\n");
    printf("Total:");
    printf("                  %d", money2);

    getch();
}
```

Changes made are

1. The array sizes are increased to 7. and `x[6] = 1` is added. This ensures that the end case is taken care of.
2. An additional variable `money2` is added to store the total money for printing at the end. In your code, the `money` variable is changed and has a value of zero by the time it reaches the print function.

Comment: what if its not divisible by 20 how to make it invalid